# "All comments" mod tool tabs too far right

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

So us mods have a cool new tool. Neat. But where are these neat tabs I've heard so much about?
[image]

Oh. They're eight miles to the right of the page:

[image: screenshot]

This is what it looks like if your monitor is wide enough:

[image: screenshot]

<sub>Or if you have two monitors and stretch the window really wide</sub>

The tabs are borked at least on UX and all "Grainy" Beta styled sites. You can see this menu by using the "mod" link on a user's profile, the "info", then "comments".

This is how it appears on Drupal Answers, on a 1600x900 monitor.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: they better do it right this time (but lets hope not too right)

Comment: no repro on Arqade... several days later